# Make a function for a nested for loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I want to make a function for a nested for loop in order to avoid having to copy and paste the loop.

I can make a nested for loop into an array so that I only need to copy-paste a single for loop, but that basically means that it takes twice as long to run.

Of course, I can save that array so the function would only need to be called once, but it would be nice if there was a way to send arguments to that function.

I wrote an example for my idea:

```js
function exampleForLoop(num){
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < num; j++){
            for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                arr.push([i,j,k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

let exampleArr = exampleForLoop(3);
for (let i = 0; i < exampleArr.length; i++){
    console.log(exampleArr[i]);
}

let exampleArr2 = exampleForLoop(1);
for (let i = 0; i < exampleArr2.length; i++){
    console.log(exampleArr2[i]);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem, you are facing?

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a way of doing that without running the for loop twice, or just overall better, but I found a solution and answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make each code that would be in the for loop a separate function, you can send the names of those functions as a parameter of the for loop function, and then you can use functionName(i, j, k) to call them.

Code:

```js
function exampleForLoop(functionName, num){
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < num; j++){
            for (let k = 0; k < 4; k++){
                functionName(i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
}

function exampleFunction1(i, j, k){
    console.log(i, j, k);
}

function exampleFunction2(i, j, k){
    console.log(i, j, k);
}

exampleForLoop(exampleFunction1, 3);
exampleForLoop(exampleFunction2, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go even a step ahead and use a recursive function for the loops along with an array of limits for each loop (starting with zero) and hand over a function which parameters correspond to the looped values.

```js
function loop(limits, fn, values = [], result = []) {
    if (!limits.length) {
        result.push(fn(...values));
        return result;
    }
    for (let i = 0, l = limits.shift(); i < l; i++) {
        loop([...limits], fn, [...values, i], result);
    }
    return result;
}

loop([2, 3, 3], (...a) => a).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
console.log('');
loop([2, 1, 3], (...a) => a).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly with the example, but if you wanted to set where each loop starts and the increment for each one, then it might be a bit hard to read, also it's a bit difficult to do something between the loops. Nice answer tho!